How to run individual tagged tests in behaviour spec
Per documentation I should be free to mix spec and test tags like below with enabled tag inheritance
@Tags("Linux")
class ImportantBDDTest :
    BehaviorSpec({
         given("precondition exist") {
            `when`("trigger happen") {
                then("assert confirmed").config(tags = setOf(Debian) {
                }
             }
          }
})

However when I run ./gradlew test -Dkotest.tags='Linux & Debian' then nothing is run  as apparently given leaf is already considered as lacking the Debian tag and ignored along with its children. It is not possible to set .config on given function.
What should be a way to run only a test with Debian tag?
Project config is
class ProjectConfiguration : AbstractProjectConfig() {
    override var displayFullTestPath: Boolean? = true
    override var isolationMode = IsolationMode.InstancePerTest
    override var duplicateTestNameMode = DuplicateTestNameMode.Silent
    override var tagInheritance = true
    override val testNameAppendTags = true
}

Gradle task has systemProperties = System.getProperties().asIterable().associate { it.key.toString() to it.value }
Versions: kotest 5.9.1, JVM 21.0.5 and gradle 8.11.1

So far only working approach is to move such test to own class and use @Tags("Linux", "Debian") which is clumsy.
